# How to make other groups unselectable when you select an option of one group in md-select?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to implement a drop down list using

```
<md-select>
```

and

```
<md-optgroup>.
```

I am following the example "Option Groups" here: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/select

But what I want to implement is a little bit complex. Once the user select an option under a group, then all the options in the other groups will be grey (cannot be selected). Only the options in the same group are still selectable.

For example, if the user select "Bacon" for the toppings first, then only "Pepperoni", "Sausage", "Ground Beef" are still selectable. Other options under VEGGIES are all disabled. Unless the user deselect "Bacon", then all the options under VEGGIES become available again.

Does anyone have a solution for this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could disable an item by ng-disabled.
You should accomplish this by disabling all item which doesn't have the same category as the one already selected.

```
$scope.toppings = [
    { category: 'meat', name: 'Pepperoni' },
    { category: 'meat', name: 'Sausage' },
    { category: 'meat', name: 'Ground Beef' },
    { category: 'meat', name: 'Bacon' },
    { category: 'veg', name: 'Mushrooms' },
    { category: 'veg', name: 'Onion' },
    { category: 'veg', name: 'Green Pepper' },
    { category: 'veg', name: 'Green Olives' }
];
$scope.selectedToppings = [];
$scope.isDisabled = function(item) {
  return $scope.selectedToppings.length && (item.category !== $scope.selectedToppings[0].category);
};
```

and your html:

```
<md-option ng-disabled="isDisabled(topping)" ng-value="topping" ng-repeat="topping in toppings | filter: {category: 'meat' }">{{topping.name}}</md-option>
```

Comment: Thank you. Your idea works. But the codes are not completely correct. Some edits: ng-value="topping", otherwise selectedToppings.category is undefined. You also need to deal with the case when selectedToppings.length == 0 separately, otherwise when you deselected all the selected options, the disabled options won't become available again.

Comment: By the way, is it possible to add a feature that the group name can also be selected? When you select the group name, all the options in the group will be selected and options in other group will be disabled. Thank you.

Comment: you are right by the ng-value="topping". About the selectedToppings.length == 0 separately, it's not necessary. About the feature, i don't think it's possible, but you can add another custom option to select all, before every options loop.

Comment: when selectedToppings.length is zero, you will get error when you try to access $scope.selectedToppings[0], so you have to check if selectedToppings.length is zero, if it is not zero, you then can access $scope.selectedToppings[0].

Comment: @user3293338 it already checks if length is not 0 (means not false). return $scope.selectedToppings.length && ....    http://embed.plnkr.co/UeQjjGNbSM1tn1RVFKzT/

Comment: ok, this is wired. Cause when I execute "return $scope.selectedToppings.length && (item.category !== $scope.selectedToppings[0].category);", there will be an error if the length is zero. Because $scope.selectedToppings[0].category doesn't exist when the length is zero. This doesn't affect the code to be functioning. Just seeing error msg in the console makes me uncomfortable. But it seems fine in your demo.